# Post category insert checkbox values into database

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to insert from a form in my application a new row in a documents table (which works fine)but to also insert a row into a join table upon submission also, I believe I am close to resolving the issue but still able to get it to update the join table.

I list the available categories like this within the new document form:

```
<?php

$q = "SELECT * FROM cats";  

$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

echo '<div class="view_body">';

// FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
echo '<br><input type="checkbox" name="cats['.$row['cat_id'].']"> '.$row["cat_name"]. '</label>';
}
echo '</div>'; 

?>
```

My script to insert the entire form looks like this:

```
<?php
require ('../../db_con.php');

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// FORM VALIDATION & SUBMISSION
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $errors = array(); // BEGIN AN ERRORS ARRAY

    // CHECK FIRST NAME
    if (empty($_POST['doc_name'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter a document name.';   
    } else {
        $dn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['doc_name']));
    }

    // CHECK LAST NAME
    if (empty($_POST['doc_content'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter any document content.';   
    } else {
        $dc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['doc_content']));
    }

    // POST CAT ID
    if ($_POST['cat_id']) {
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['cat_id']));  
    } 


    if (empty($errors)) {

        // MAKING THE QUERY

        $q = "INSERT INTO docs (doc_name, doc_content, created_date) VALUES ('$dn', '$dc', NOW() )";          

        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

        if ($r) { 



        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

            // REDIRECT BACK TO DOCUMENT LIST
            echo("<script>location.href = 'list_doc.php';</script>");

        } else {

            // ERROR CHECKING!
            echo '<h1>System Error!</h1> <p>you could not be registered because of a system error!<br></p>';             

            // DEBUGGIN MESSAGE
            echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br><br>query: ' . $q . '</p>';
    }


        $cat_ids=isset($_POST['cats'])&&is_array($_POST['cats'])?array_keys($_POST['cats']):array();

        $query="INSERT INTO cat_doc_join (cat_id,doc_id) VALUES";

        $length=count($cat_ids); 

        for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){ 
            $query.='('.$cat_ids[$i].','.$doc_id.')'; 

        if($i<$length-1) 
            $query.=','; 

        }        


        mysqli_close($dbc);
        exit();

    } else {

        // REPORT THE ERRORS
        echo '<h1>Error!</h1><p class="error">The Following error(s) have occured:<br>';
        foreach ($errors as $msg) {
            echo " - $msg<br>\n";
        }
        echo '</p><p>Please try again!.</p><p><br></p>';

    }

}
?>
```

I am struggling to get the join table to do an insert, If i do a var_dump on the $_POST I know it is grabbing all the fields and checkboxes I have selected but now its a matter o inserting that. I am really struggling at this point so any help would be thankful.

**UPDATED**

Here is the form:

```
<?php

    include 'includes/header.php';
    include 'actions/new_doc.inc.php';

?>



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-group-1">

            <h1>New document</h1>

            <form action="new_doc.php" method="post">
                <br>
                <input style="width:50%;" placeholder="Document Name" type="text" name="doc_name" autocomplete="off" name="doc_name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['doc_name'])) echo $_POST['doc_name']; ?>" />

        </div>          
</div>  


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-group-1"> 
    <?php

    $q = "SELECT * FROM cats";  

    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

    echo '<div class="view_body">';

    // FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    echo '<br><input type="checkbox" name="cats['.$row['cat_id'].']"> '.$row["cat_name"]. '</label>';
    }
    echo '</div>'; 

    ?>
    </div>
</div>        


<br>    


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-group-1 wysiwyg_toolbar">    

        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ibold()" title="Bold Text"><i class="fa fa-bold"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="iitalic()" title="Italic Text"><i class="fa fa-italic"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="iunderline()" title="Underline Text"><i class="fa fa-underline"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ifontName()" title="Font Family"><i class="fa fa-font"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ifontsize()" title="Font Size"><i class="fa fa-text-height"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ifontcolor()" title="Font Colour"><i class="fa fa-eraser"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ihiliteColor()" title="Highlight Text"><i class="fa fa-magic"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ilink()" title="Add/Edit Link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="iunlink()" title="Remove Link"><i class="fa fa-chain-broken"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ijustifyLeft()" title="Text align-left"><i class="fa fa-align-left"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ijustifyCenter()" title="Text align-center"><i class="fa fa-align-center"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ijustifyRight()" title="Text align-right"><i class="fa fa-align-right"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onClick="iUnorderedList()" title="Unordered List"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onClick="iOrderedList()" title="Ordered List"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtnUndo" type="button" onClick="iUndo()" title="Undo last change"><i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtnRedo" type="button" onClick="iRedo()" title="Redo last change"><i class="fa fa-rotate-right"></i></button>
        <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onClick="iImage()" title="Image Upload"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></button>

    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-group-1">        

                <textarea name="doc_content" id="doc_content" placeholder="Document Content" style="display: none;"></textarea>
                <iframe name="editor" id="editor" style="height: 600px;"></iframe>

                <br><br> 
                <input onclick="formsubmit()" type="submit" value="Create Document" name="submit"/>
            </form>

    </div>
</div>







<p><a href="list_doc.php">Back to document list</a></p>
```

Here is the action script:

```
<?php
require ('../../db_con.php');

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// FORM VALIDATION & SUBMISSION
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $errors = array(); // BEGIN AN ERRORS ARRAY

    // CHECK FIRST NAME
    if (empty($_POST['doc_name'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter a document name.';   
    } else {
        $dn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['doc_name']));
    }

    // CHECK LAST NAME
    if (empty($_POST['doc_content'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter any document content.';   
    } else {
        $dc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['doc_content']));
    }

    // POST CAT ID
    if ($_POST['cat_id']) {
        mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['cat_id']));  
    } 


    if (empty($errors)) {

        // MAKING THE QUERY

        $q = "INSERT INTO docs (doc_name, doc_content, created_date) VALUES ('$dn', '$dc', NOW() )";          

        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

        if ($r) { 


        $cat_ids=isset($_POST['cats'])&&is_array($_POST['cats'])?array_keys($_POST['cats']):array();

        $query="INSERT INTO cat_doc_join (cat_id,doc_id) VALUES";

        $length=count($cat_ids); 

        for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){ 
            $query.='('.$cat_ids[$i].','.$doc_id.')'; 

        if($i<$length-1) 
            $query.=','; 

        }        


        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        mysqli_close($dbc);

            // REDIRECT BACK TO DOCUMENT LIST
            echo("<script>location.href = 'list_doc.php';</script>");

        } else {

            // ERROR CHECKING!
            echo '<h1>System Error!</h1> <p>you could not be registered because of a system error!<br></p>';             

            // DEBUGGIN MESSAGE
            echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br><br>query: ' . $q . '</p>';
    }

    } else {

        // REPORT THE ERRORS
        echo '<h1>Error!</h1><p class="error">The Following error(s) have occured:<br>';
        foreach ($errors as $msg) {
            echo " - $msg<br>\n";
        }
        echo '</p><p>Please try again!.</p><p><br></p>';

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: why is `mysqli_query($dbc, $query);` above `$query="INSERT INTO cat_doc_join (cat_id,doc_id) VALUES";...`? kind of like putting the wagon before the horse

Comment: haha love how you put that, you are right it is me being new to php and this area is REALLY new to me trying to update a join table

Comment: hehe, love people with a good sense of humour ;-)

Comment: I am being so thick here and really not getting why I cannot update the join table, any ideas - I updated my question (Sorry it is LOOONG!)

Comment: wish I could help, but JOINS aren't what I am good at. am getting there though ;-)

Comment: Oh cmon I know your a bit of a genius! ;)

Comment: if I had time sure, but it's Friday and I'm sipping cappuccinos today. ;-)

Comment: How very dare you be all continental at this time of the day on a Friday - I find it highly unacceptable! Please help =`{

Comment: *Continental Ralph?* Then what do I get for sipping coffee & chicory @Fred-ii-?

Comment: A good feeling? @JayBlanchard *hic!* oops, that's me falling into the pickle barrel Sam. Is a contitnental "breakfast" included in there too?

Comment: *I could eat Ralph.* But I want something more substantial like eggs, bacon, grits, hash-browns, sausage, etc... @Fred-ii-

Comment: Gentleman, Gentleman, please now spare me some of your knowledge I would be entirely grateful, PLEASE :D

Comment: Add some *actual* error checking to your queries @phpcoder, like `mysqli_error()`. Additionally you can look in your error logs and you will find out what the issue is.

Comment: I am quite new to php so please be gentle :( I will see if I can fathom out the issue with using your suggested function - but any suggestions to the above would be kinda awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't get to the second insert query because of

> ```
>   // REDIRECT BACK TO DOCUMENT LIST
>   echo("<script>location.href = 'list_doc.php';</script>");
> ```

try with:

```
<?php

$q = "SELECT * FROM cats";  

$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

echo '<div class="view_body">';

// FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
echo '<br><label><input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row["cat_name"] . '</label>';
}
echo '</div>'; 

?>
```

---

```
<?php 

require ('../../db_con.php'); 

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 

// FORM VALIDATION & SUBMISSION 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 

$errors = array(); // BEGIN AN ERRORS ARRAY 
// CHECK FIRST NAME 
if (empty($_POST['doc_name'])) { 
$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter a document name.'; 
} else { 
$dn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['doc_name'])); 
} 

// CHECK LAST NAME 
if (empty($_POST['doc_content'])) { 
$errors[] = 'You forgot to enter any document content.'; 
} else { 
$dc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['doc_content'])); 
} 

// POST CAT ID 
//if ($_POST['cat_id']) { 
//mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['cat_id'])); 
//} 






if (empty($errors)) { 

// MAKING THE QUERY 

$q = "INSERT INTO docs (doc_name, doc_content, created_date) VALUES ('$dn', '$dc', NOW() )"; 

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q); 

if ($r) { 


$doc_id = mysqli_insert_id($dbc); 

$query = "INSERT INTO cat_doc_join (cat_id,doc_id) VALUES "; 
$cat_ids = $_POST['cat_id']; 
$length = count($cat_ids); 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($cat_ids); $i++) { 
$query.='(' . $cat_ids[$i] . ',' . $doc_id . ')'; 

if ($i < $length - 1) 
$query.=','; 
} 

mysqli_query($dbc, $query); 
mysqli_close($dbc); 

// REDIRECT BACK TO DOCUMENT LIST 
echo("<script>location.href = 'list_doc.php';</script>"); 
} else { 

// ERROR CHECKING! 
echo '<h1>System Error!</h1> <p>you could not be registered because of a system error!<br></p>'; 

// DEBUGGIN MESSAGE 
echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br><br>query: ' . $q . '</p>'; 
} 
} else { 

// REPORT THE ERRORS 
echo '<h1>Error!</h1><p class="error">The Following error(s) have occured:<br>'; 
foreach ($errors as $msg) { 
echo " - $msg<br>\n"; 
} 
echo '</p><p>Please try again!.</p><p><br></p>'; 
} 
} 
?>
```

Comment: So now I have updated it tells me I have an undefined variable: Notice: Undefined index: cat_id in C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin\actions\new_doc.inc.php on line 24 which refers to // POST CAT ID
if ($_POST['cat_id']) {
    mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['cat_id']));  
}

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your edit, I am still not getting it to post into the join table where on earth is this going on?

Comment: could you show me the whole content of $query please?

Comment: Ok now I get `Notice: Undefined index: cat_id in C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin\actions\new_doc.inc.php on line 27`

`Notice: Undefined variable: query in C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin\actions\new_doc.inc.php on line 45`

Comment: Which is referring to the cat_id used in the $_POST query and also not being able to execute the $query as I killed the script

Comment: I hope that helped? Sorry I am really struggling with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81647/discussion-between-gotrekk-and-phpcoder).